# Regression Plot in Altair doesn't show any output

Tags: python, linear-regression, altair

Hello I'm trying to plot a regression with altair from a pandas dataframe but it doesnt't show the regression just the scatter points.
Here is my code:

```
import altair as alt

fig=alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
x=alt.X("Year",scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
y=alt.Y("Air Temperature",scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
color=alt.Color("Air Temperature", scale=alt.Scale(scheme="inferno")))

fit=fig.transform_regression("Year","Air Temperature").mark_line()

fit+fig
```

I tried this code with different colums from the dataframe but it never showed the regression line. If i just plot the fit i get an empty diagram.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Is your 'Year' column temporal data type in pandas? You might want to change it to an int if that is the case. If that doesn't help, could you post a sample of your data as text?

Comment: I also tried the different encoding Data types(https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encoding.html) from altair but none of them showed any results.

Comment: I also tried using pandas.to_numeric() but the result was the same, If i triy to plot the linear regression with plotly express there is no problem

Comment: Please post a sample of your data or recreate the issue with one of the vega_datasets from the Altair docs so that we can try reproducing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your regression chart includes the color encoding, so a different regression line will be drawn for each unique temperature. My guess is that every temperature value is unique, so each regression line is a single point.

If you'd rather draw a single regression line for *all* data, then you should avoid using a color encoding for this layer; for example:

```python
base = alt.Chart(df).encode(
  x=alt.X("Year",scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
  y=alt.Y("Air Temperature",scale=alt.Scale(zero=False))
)

fig = base.encode(
  color=alt.Color("Air Temperature", scale=alt.Scale(scheme="inferno"))
).mark_point()

fit = base.transform_regression("Year","Air Temperature").mark_line()

fit+fig
```